# Is h3 inside td tag, accessibility compliant?

Tags: html, uiaccessibility

I had to place an `<h3>` tag inside `<td>`, but the voice over is not reading the text inside `<h3>` tag. Earlier when the `<h3>` was inside `<div>`, voice over / talkback were reading the text inside `<h3>`. Can someone please suggest how can I use `<h3>` inside `<td>` and still make it accessibility compliant?

Comment: are you using JAWS Screen reader?

Comment: No @Monkey_Dev1300, I tried using Voiceover on Mac and Talkback on Android

Comment: Can you use `<th>` instead and style it to meet your needs? I'm not sure it's best practice to put header tags inside a table